# Parental controls for TPLINK Archer C7

Tags: wireless-access-point

I have a TPLINK Archer C7 wifi  router. I want to stop my children's iPads from accessing the internet between 9 PM and midnight everyday.

The Archer C7 has an administrative controls offering "parental controls" and "access controls". Unfortunately, the documentation on how to use these administrative functions makes absolutely no sense to me. Given a MAC address, how do I configure this thing to shut off access to my kid's iPad for 3 hours a day?

Comment: We use the Parent Contorl, but the kids phones and iPads cant access the internet. After i log on to the Admin window of the router and click the clock on the Insights if start working. Not very convenient when we are not at home.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use the guest network. The guest network can be configured to start and stop service at a particular time of day. The kids' devices are now connected to the guest network, which stops providing service at 21:00. The rest of the household devices are connected to the main network, which provides service 24/7.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do this.

1. I set DHCP to assign IP addresses that are only .100 or greater. For example, 192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.254.  Anything that gets an IP in that range is considered a kid or "non-privileged" machine.
2. For the adult phones/computers, I used the "Address Reservation" function to assign them IPs in the 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.99 range.
3. Finally, I use the "Access Control" section to deny certain websites to the "non-privileged" IP addresses. For example, here is screenshot of how I (try to) keep the kids off YouTube:

[image]

It works fine as long as you use the Archer Router for DHCP. A few months ago I switched to use pihole's DHCP server. Thee Archer's Access Controls no longer block the kids' machines.